# MergeRecord - control name of output

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a fairly simple process that merges xml files into one or more XML files, using the MergeRecord processor.  I'm then converting them into JSON and writing them out with PutFile.  The files come out with fabulous names like **79f000ec-9da1-4b59-a0a8-79cc3bb5e85a**.

Is there any way to control those file names, or at least give them an appropriate extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beforeyour putFile use updateAttribut processor and rename ${fileName}

Exemple :

[image]